# Removing indent after an equation which was wrapped in a command

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have found that if one wraps a command around an equation, for example

```
Text here!
\textcolor{red}{%
    \begin{equation}% 
        E = mc^2 
    \end{equation}%
}% 
Text here too!
```

then the text following this equation will have an additional indentation. How can this indentation be removed?

Comment: Not on my machine. And you could always do `\begin{equation} 
\textcolor{red}{
        E = mc^2 } 
    \end{equation}Text....`

Comment: @marmot I need to wrap the equations in a command. The example given is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

> How can this indentation be removed?

Answer: Don't place the `equation` environment in a `\textcolor{red}{...}` "wrapper". Instead, write

```
\begin{equation}
\color{red}
    E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
```

Note that the scope of the statement `\color{red}` ends at `\end{equation}`.

Comment: I need to wrap the equations in a command. I am submitting corrections to a referee and all the corrections should be marked in red, which is to be achieved by wrapping the all corrections in a function. I have created a function `\newcommand{\lr}[1]{\ifreferee\textcolor{red}{#1}\else#1\fi}` and a corresponding boolean `referee` that I can toggle. Now I wrap everything in `\lr{}` when I want corrections. The {} around the #1 is the source of the problems. Can your answer be please updated to account for this?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron - please provide more information about how `\ifreferee` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I see no indent. Anyway, that's not the best way to color equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newenvironment{colordisplay}[1]
 {\leavevmode\color{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
\begin{align}
E&=mc^2 \\
F&=nd^2
\end{align}
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
\begin{colordisplay}{red}
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
\end{colordisplay}
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
\begin{colordisplay}{red}
\begin{align}
E&=mc^2 \\
F&=nd^2
\end{align}
\end{colordisplay}
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!
Text here too! Text here too! Text here too! Text here too!

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is used just to see the text block margins.

[image]